# Mapbox navigation api return 422 unprocessable entity

Tags: api, mapbox

I'm trying to call the mapbox api to get navigation instructions.

Here's the doc: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/#using-http-post

And here's my api call:

```
fetch(`https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/walking?access_token=${Config.MAPBOX_API_KEY}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    coordinates: "2.344003,48.85805;2.34675,48.85727;",
  }),
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Unfortunately I get a 422 unprocessable entity error:

[image]

I have tried differente coordinates as well...do you guys know what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing your coordinates in as a string, but the API expects a number, which is why you're getting a `422`. Try this:

```
fetch(`https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/walking?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYmRkYXZpZHNvbiIsImEiOiJjaW41MWU5bTcwY2k1dXdtNG54cnhlczFsIn0._R6SrAak5_qF8l31JvSBIA`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  body: 'coordinates=2.344003,48.85805;2.34675,48.85727',  // <--- Body changed to pass numbers instead of strings
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```